# How to load key/value pairs from properties file loaded via PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a property file with key/value pairs that looks like below:

```
#state/city/counties

fl.regionA.counties=abc,def,ghi,jkl
fl.regionB.counties=xyz,qrs,tuv,wxy
```

The property file is loaded via code snippet below:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

@Bean
public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer properties(){
...
}
```

How can I load the a list of StateRegionMappings where StateRegionMapping:

```
public class StateRegionMapping{
   private List<String> counties;
   private String state;
   private String region;

   ...

}
```

Update 5/23/2017:

My other alternate key/value structure is like this:

```
states.config[0].state=fl
states.config[0].name=regionA
states.config[0].counties=abc,def,ghi,jkl
states.config[1].state=fl
states.config[1].name=regionB
states.config[1].counties=xyz,qrs,tuv,wxy
```

Comment: You will have access to properties in the loaded file via ${propertyName} in either spring xml files or @Value annotation. If I am not wrong, what you are trying to do is load all the properties into a list of StateRegionMapping. If that is what you are trying to do, PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer is not the right thing to use.

Answer (score 3):

If I get you right, you want to configure a list of states where each state has a region and each region a list of counties. With properties files this would look like this:

```
states-config.states[0].name=fl
states-config.states[0].regions[0].name=regionA
states-config.states[0].regions[0].counties[0]=abc
states-config.states[0].regions[0].counties[1]=def
states-config.states[0].regions[0].counties[2]=ghi
states-config.states[0].regions[0].counties[3]=jkl
states-config.states[0].regions[1].name=regionB
states-config.states[0].regions[1].counties[0]=xyz
states-config.states[0].regions[1].counties[1]=qrs
states-config.states[0].regions[1].counties[2]=tuv
states-config.states[0].regions[1].counties[3]=wxy
```

With YAML this is a bit more readable:

```
states-config:
  states:
    - name: fl
      regions:
        - name: regionA
          counties:
            - abc
            - def
            - ghi
            - jkl
        - name: regionB
          counties:
            - xyz
            - qrs
            - tuv
            - wxy
```

The needed java config would look like this:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("states-config")
public class Config {

    private List<State> states = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<State> getStates() {
        return states;
    }

    public void setStates(List<State> states) {
        this.states = states;
    }

    public static class State {
        private String name;
        private List<Region> regions = new ArrayList<>();

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }


        public List<Region> getRegions() {
            return regions;
        }

        public void setRegions(List<Region> regions) {
            this.regions = regions;
        }
    }

    public static class Region {
        private String name;
        private List<String> counties = new ArrayList<>();

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public List<String> getCounties() {
            return counties;
        }

        public void setCounties(List<String> counties) {
            this.counties = counties;
        }
    }

}
```

To your update: this would work with the following config using your StateRegionMapping class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("states")
public class Config {

    private List<StateRegionMapping> config = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<StateRegionMapping> getConfig() {
        return config;
    }

    public void setConfig(List<StateRegionMapping> config) {
        this.config = config;
    }
}
```

Just one minor change: since in your `StateRegionMapping` class the region is named `region`, your must use this also in the properties instead of `name`:

```
states.config[0].state=fl
states.config[0].region=regionA
....
```

Comment: Will this also work with properties file that are key/value pairs (not hierarchical like yaml)? I updated the question with the alternate key/value structure.

Comment: I was on the right track when trying to load the configuration. It did load the some of my key/value pairs except the ones that are of `List` types. Reason being, my field name was pluralized (eg `configs` instead of `confg`). A user error in my part. Thanks for the answer and that deserves an upvote!

Answer (score 2):

It is absolutely possible! Try this.

This should be present in your class where you want to load.

```
@Value("#{${passingscore.subjectwise}}")
private Map<String, String> passingScorePerSubjectMap;
```

The should be present in the application.properties file and define the key-value map properties like below.

```
passingscore.subjectwise= {'Maths': '40','Physics':'50','Chemistry':'70'}
```